# Как работает "nonlocal" в Python?

Tags: python

подскажите пожалуйста, как работает "nonlocal" в Python?

Answer (score 4):

При объявлении переменной через nonlocal она будет ссылаться на переменную с таким же именем в ближайшем замыкании, исключая глобальные переменные

Например, объявление без nonlocal

```
x = 0
def outer():
    x = 1
    def inner():
        x = 2
        print("inner:", x)

    inner()
    print("outer:", x)

outer()
print("global:", x)

# inner: 2
# outer: 1
# global: 0
```

А теперь с nonlocal, x в inner() равна x в outer()

```
x = 0
def outer():
    x = 1
    def inner():
        nonlocal x
        x = 2
        print("inner:", x)

    inner()
    print("outer:", x)

outer()
print("global:", x)

# inner: 2
# outer: 2
# global: 0
```

А с global будет так

```
x = 0
def outer():
    x = 1
    def inner():
        global x
        x = 2
        print("inner:", x)

    inner()
    print("outer:", x)

outer()
print("global:", x)

# inner: 2
# outer: 1
# global: 2
```

Comment: Большое спасибо всё предельно ясно и понятно

Comment: Прошу прощения, немного непонятно как работает global